# C++ Non-QT interface and QtNetwork

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

I'm part of the RoboCup SSL of my school and we try to simulate the entire game on the grSim simulator (https://github.com/mani-monaj/grSim).

grSim is a  Qt application so I have used the Qt Network library to make a client/server app and receive Google protobuf data. (https://github.com/rjabaker/WarBots-StrategyTester/tree/master/tester/comm)

I have try to make the samething with SSL-refbox, I receive data, but it's not working when I try to print out the data, so I try to figure out why..

** So my question is: Can I use the Qt Network library to make a client/server app and receive data from a non-Qt interface (SSL-Refbox https://github.com/Hawk777/ssl-refbox/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- the Qt network library doesn't specify any particular protocol, it just shovels bytes around.  So there is no reason a Qt-network-based server can't talk to a non-Qt-network-based client, or vice versa; you just have to make sure that they both speak the same protocol.